# Filter out events

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I have a TellstickDuo, a small device capable of sending signals to my lamps at home to turn them on or off based on a schedule. This device sends around 3-5 "on-signals" and "off-signals" every time i press the remote control button (to make sure at least one signal is sent correctly i guess!?). I also have a Raspberry Pi that listens for these signals and starts a script when a specific signal is found (based on the lamp-devices id´s).

The problem is that everytime when it sends 3-5 signals my script runs the same amount of times but i only want it to run once. Is there any way to capture these signals and with bash (.sh) ignore everyone but one ?

Code sent from device:

```
...RUNNING /usr/bin/php /var/www/autosys/python_to_raw.php "class:command;protocol:arctech;model:selflearning;house:13741542;unit:10;group:0;method:turnon;"
...RUNNING /usr/bin/php /var/www/autosys/python_to_raw.php "class:command;protocol:arctech;model:selflearning;house:13741542;unit:10;group:0;method:turnon;"
...RUNNING /usr/bin/php /var/www/autosys/python_to_raw.php "class:command;protocol:arctech;model:selflearning;house:13741542;unit:10;group:0;method:turnon;"
...RUNNING /usr/bin/php /var/www/autosys/python_to_raw.php "class:command;protocol:arctech;model:selflearning;house:13741542;unit:10;group:0;method:turnon;"
```

and my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ( "${RAWDATA}" == *13741542* ) && ( "${RAWDATA}" == *turnon* ) ]]; then
    # Something will be done here, like turn on a lamp, send an email or something else
fi
```

(Some explanation to the RAWDATA code can be found here: http://developer.telldus.com/blog/2012/11/new-ways-to-script-execution-from-signals)

If i set my bash-script to send an email i get 4 emails, if i set it to update a counter at my local webpage it updates it 4 times. 
There is no way to controll how many signals the device will send, but can i only capture it once somehow? Maybe some way to "run script on first signal and drop everything else for 5 seconds"

Comment: if a `sleep 5` inside your `if` test doesn't solve the problem, then you need to show us how your script is "getting" the transmission from TellstickDuo. Good luck.

Comment: Do you meen i should sleep inside the IF or after the THEN ?

Comment: `if [[ ( ...... ) && ( ..... ) ]] ; then sleep 5 ; # do other stuff; fi` Also, I don't think you need the enclosing parens. Good luck.

Comment: Hmm, it sleeps 5 seconds, 5 times :P I will see if i can find the script that gets the transmissions.

Comment: Yes, will need to see more context. Good luck.